# How does MongoDB handle range and nearest neighbor queries?

Tags: mongodb, nearest-neighbor, spatial-index, geohashing

How does MongoDB handle range and nearest neighbor queries? what algorithms used?

I know MongoDB use GeoHash and B-Tree to index spatial data but how it handle the range and nearest neighbor queries are never mentioned in any doc.

Also, MongoDB can only handle 100 NN by using $near. That may implies that the NN algorithm is not efficient?

Comment: The source code is available [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo). I'd suggest you look there if you want to look for inefficiencies.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, the question was "how does mongo handle NN". Pointing to a humongous repo of code is both unhelpful and patronizing.